# Does anyone know what mode or key this is?

Tags: harmony

Does anyone know what mode or key this is?
It ends on A and it seems a bit minor. It could be Dorian with Do on G. 
It seems very much like some kind of Gregorian melody and it doesn't even have a time signature.
[image]

Comment: You need to re-phrase this, otherwise it'll be deleted as not permissable. Perhaps - what would make this appear to be modal?

Comment: This sounds like A minor with a dorian melody.

Comment: It's in A Dorian.

Comment: If a simple re-phrasing turns a question from not permissible to permissible, perhaps the policing could be a little less pedantic?

Comment: @ScottWallace - A minor with a Dorian melody actually gets called A Dorian. Dorian *is* minor, and tonic is A. Thus A Dorian.

Comment: @Tim In what sense is Dorian minor?

Comment: @k.stm - the defining factor is m3 from its root. Same goes for Phrygian and of course Aeolian.

Answer (score 1):

This must be A hypodorian, the plagal mode of dorian:

Finalis = A, repercussio = C (the 3rd also called tenor or reciting tone)

*In addition, the note F, corresponding to the reciting note or tenor of the second psalm tone, was regarded as an important secondary center.*

This quote is referring to D hypodorian, so F will be C in A dorian.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypodorian_mode

May be we are violating this melody by forcing it to fit in a modal scheme. Couldn‘t we say as well it is A aeolian and modulating to E aeolian? (3rd  phrase) ...?

Answer (score 0):

If the tonic was G, it would be in G major!  The melody pretty clearly centres on A.   So it's A Dorian.

Think of the 'usual' Dorian scale - The notes of a C major scale but starting on D.  This is the notes of a G major scale but starting on A.

(So I sort of see what you meant by 'Dorian with Do on G'.)

Comment: Would Dorian not have (moveable) do as its 'tonic'? Would that tonic be known as re? Not sure. I was only trying to save a question from the bin. It's fairly obvious that it's in A Dorian, but  just putting that hardly helps anyone. I know - you expanded.

Comment: And strict, pedantic answer to the header will be 'Yes, more than likely'.

Comment: Yeah.  You take my point.  Pedantic validation of questions can get silly.